# Delay emission of observable until the execution of the current Angular tick has finished

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

In my Angular app, I have a bunch of `Observable`s that emit notifications when certain data changes. Sometimes, I'll run into a case where I need to notify several `Observable`s about data changes in rapid succession:

```
// Subscribers for observable1 are immediately notified.
observable1.next(...)

// Subscribers for observable2 are immediately notified.
observable2.next(...)
```

This can sometimes cause annoying bugs, however. I frequently run into situations where the order in which `Observable`s are notified can cause unexpected behavior. For example, the subscribers for `observable1` might execute code that assumes the subscribers for `observable2` have already been notified.

Basically, I am looking for a way to delay the emission of items to subscribers until the current Angular tick has completed. For example, something like:

```
observable1.next(...)
observable2.next(...)

// At the end of the current Angular tick, the subscribers
// for observable1 and observable2 are notified.
```

Or perhaps there is some other `rxjs` operator that I could use to achieve something similar...

Comment: Do the subscribers to `observable1` and `observable2` know anything about _each other_?

Comment: No, they don't. The way I've structured things right now is so that each observable operates as a content notification system for disjoint parts of my application state. The problem is that the subscribers often make use of data from both `observable1` and `observable2`. So when a subscriber for `observable1` gets a notification that its data has changed, it might retrieve data held by `observable2`. This is where the order in which `observable1` and `observable2` are notified begins to matter... because subscribers for `observable1` will retrieve slightly out-of-date data from `observable2`.

Comment: "For example, the subscribers for observable1 might execute code that assumes the subscribers for observable2 have already been notified." that seems it's more a problem of stucture (maybe on the subscribers part ?), observables are precisely done to avoid such behaviors. It sounds like what you are looking for is kind of a hack to circumvent that problem instead of really fixing it.

Comment: @n00dl3 Sorry, I should have been more clear. The problem isn't that the subscribers for `observable1` assume that the subscribers for `observable2` have already been notified. The problem is that the subscribers for `observable1` assume that they can safely call `observable2.getValue()` in order to get the most up-to-date data (I'm using a `BehaviorSubject` in each of my services to store the most recent copy of the data).

Comment: @n00dl3 That said it's definitely possible I have the wrong structure... but if that is the case I guess I am wondering what would the right structure be? I guess essentially what I am looking for is the ability to set data on a bunch of services/observables and then batch notify all of the affected subscribers at once (but only after all of the data has been set).

Comment: You may be looking for [*schedulers*](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Scheduler.js~Scheduler.html); you should be able to write your own if it's necessary. However, schedulers will not necessarily help you deal with overly coupled listeners. By definition, listeners should not have such dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## To provide you with an option that will do what you want (ish).

This is a classic race condition: your subscribers to `observable1` and `observable2` claim to be independent, but they seem actually to be coupled.

I played with implementations of [`.delayWhen()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-delayWhen), but the only thing that seemed *to guarantee that both are up to date before they are used* given your current architecture is to `.zip()` the two Observables at the source, emit the result, and to have your subscribers split them:

```js
console.info('Waiting for Observables...');

const observable1 = Rx.Observable.of([1,2,3])
  .delayWhen(() => Rx.Observable.timer(1000));

const observable2 = Rx.Observable.of(['a', 'b', 'c'])
  .delayWhen(() => Rx.Observable.timer(500));

const merged = Rx.Observable.zip(observable1, observable2).share();

// Where you need the result from 1
merged.subscribe(
  next => {
    console.info("Subscriber 1");
    console.info(next[0]);
  }
);

// Where you need the result from 2
merged.subscribe(
  next => {
    console.info("Subscriber 2");
    console.info(next[1]);
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.3.0/dist/global/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

## Looks hacky?

Because it kind of is, but all we're doing is explicitly implementing a coupled state that is already coupled conceptually by the architecture.

The real solution is to somehow change the architecture so that they are not dependent (by, for example, changing the payload returned by whoever produces the two observable's data sets).

This also only works in this fairly trivial example where the total number of Observables is known and are in the same service. It quickly gets very complicated if these two conditions are exceeded.

The overall architecture is another question and outside this scope since we don't have insight into this.

Comment: Yeah... I think you are right. I probably need to tweak the overall structure a bit. Going into this project I thought that it would be good to split up my data into several different observables but I probably went a bit over the top. I'm going to try to merge the observables in question into one (with a larger payload and maybe some specific details about which parts have changed). Thanks a lot for the advice! :)

Comment: @AlexLockwood Yeah, I'm running into a similar "starting out we thought X but realized Y" scenario. Making time for refactoring is a must, it lets us as an institution make up for these realizations (when they couldn't really be known ahead of time -- evolving specs, framework, etc).